# There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I've been stumbling over this issue without being able to configure whats wrong in my sql insert statement. I need to insert a new row in a table but
 it keeps telling me that the columns in the insert statement are more than these in the clause.

Here is my statement:

```
kSqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BillsDetails ([BillID],[CallDialledID],[CallDateTime],[CallDuration],[CallNetPrice],[CallRetailPrice],[CallDiscountPrice]) VALUES ('" + strBillID + "','" + strDialledNumberID + "','" + strCallDate + "','" + strCallDuration + "','" + dCallNetPrice + "','" + dCallRetailPrice + "','" + dCallDiscountPrice + "')";//SqlStatement to Add new Bill
kSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

and each time I get this error:

> "There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause using c#. The number of values in the VALUES
>   clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT
>   statement."

apparently, its a syntax issue, since columns in the INSERT statement = number of given values.

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: `ExecuteReader` returns data. You need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead. But you have 7 column and 7 value. This sql statement works on SQL Server? And you should always use paramterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Does any of the strings that you are concatenating together contain a comma? BTW, you are wide-open SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
string cmdString="INSERT INTO BillsDetails('BillID','CallDialledID','CallDateTime','CallDuration','CallNetPrice','CallRetailPrice','CallDiscountPrice') VALUES (@val1, @va2, @val3,@val4, @va5, @val6,@val7)";
string connString = "your connection string";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandString = cmdString;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", 'your value');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", 'your value');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", 'your value');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", 'your value');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", 'your value');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6", 'your value');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val7", 'your value');
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        Catch(SqlException e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I think try use of ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader 
because ExecuteReader is reading database content instead of insertion of row
please read this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx ,.